# Rails ActiveAdmin - Update error when overriding a model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have the following code in my ActiveAdmin view:

```
ActiveAdmin.register IdeaAction, :as => "Action" do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

When I submit my edit form, I get the following:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ActionsController#update
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "update":String
```

As soon as I remove `:as => "Action"` override, it all works fine.  Is there anything else I need to tell to ActiveAdmin for the name override?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem here is the keyword "Action" which is reserved by ActiveAdmin.  The best possible solution I found was to put the override on the form (`:as => :idea_action`):

```
ActiveAdmin.register IdeaAction, :as => "Action" do
  form do :as => :idea_action |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```